# AngularJS - Leaflet - The "center" property is not defined in the main scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-leaflet-directive

I've set up leaflet.js correctly, and the map renders as expected in my app. However, I keep getting the following error message: `The "center" property is not defined in the main scope`. What am I doing wrong?

In my view:

```
<leaflet markers="markers" center="osloCenter"></leaflet>
```

In my controller:

```
function MapCtrl($scope) {
    angular.extend($scope, {
          osloCenter: {
                lat: 59.91,
                lng: 10.75,
                zoom: 12
        },
        markers: {
            osloMarker: {
                lat: 59.91,
                lng: 10.75,
                focus: true,
                draggable: false
            }
        defaults: {
            scrollWheelZoom: false
        }
    });
};
```

I've also tried the following:

```
       scope.osloCenter  = {
            lat : 59.91,
            lng : 10.75,
            zoom : 12
        };

        $scope.osloMarker = {
            lat: 59.91,
            lng: 10.75,
            focus: true,
            draggable: false
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object needs to be initialised at app level (i.e app.js) at $rootScope:

```
 function runBlock($rootScope) {
   angular.extend($rootScope, {
     center: {},
     markers: {},
   });
 }
```

then the required values can be set within the controller:

```
var centerLat = parseFloat($stateParams.lat);
var centerLng = parseFloat($stateParams.lon);

$scope.center = {
  lat: centerLat,
  lng: centerLng,
  zoom: 15
};    

$scope.markers = {
  marker: {
    lat: centerLat,
    lng: centerLng,
    focus: true,
    draggable: false
  }
};
```